# Please allow the anime and manga tags

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags

When I was asking a [question about Bleach](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/37/will-bleach-air-again) (the anime), I wanted to use/create the [anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime) tag, as I wanted to point out that the question was about the anime and not the manga.

I got the error that the anime tag is not allowed. Which is understandable (at first), but in this situation I suppose it was legit to use!

I suppose the same goes for the [manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga) tag..?

My suggestion is to do allow these tags, so people are able to specify/narrow down about what they are talking.

**Edit**: I just see that the [manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga) tag, is [being allowed](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga)?

Comment: In depth discussion: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/66/when-should-we-use-the-anime-and-manga-tags

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So, after conferring with the team, I changed my mind. We're going to allow for both [anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime) and [manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga) because they would allow for users to filter questions better, and to allow for specific canon references.

That said: I think it would be better if we treated tags the same as on [Science Fiction and Fantasy](http://scifi.stackexchange.com), where you can just state in the question that this is about the Star Wars movie, or a specific Star Wars book, etc. The tag would be [star-wars](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) and the question body specifies canon.

Comment: Someone who is only interested in anime/manga would be grateful to be able to filter out the anime/manga tag in the question overview. So by using these tags it is possible for such users. Adding `-anime` or `-manga` to the tags could help as well.

Comment: @Veger I disagree -- I think most people who are looking for info about Bleach will be able to filter out anime-only stuff from the manga without too much trouble. I don't think we *need* `-manga` and `-anime` tags.

Comment: It is not about beach, but about the `-anime` and `-manga` tags in generic. For example, I am not interested in manga (much), so I would like to filter manga specific questions using `manga` or `-manga` tags.

Comment: With respect to your new/updated answer: You are saying the anime and manga tags are allowed, but discouraged? (as it is favored to specify in the question)

Comment: @Veger I'm saying they are allowed, but ***I personally*** don't think we need them. I'm letting the community decide.

Comment: Ok, clear to me

Answer (score 6):

I think this is a horrible idea.  I can all-but-guarantee you it will become the most-overused and abused tags on the site.

> Questions tagged [anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime)
>   This tag indicates that the question is specific to the anime version of a series that exists as both anime and manga, or movie(s).

I get that some questions are about an anime-specific version of the work —  so describe that in your question; not with tags. Otherwise, we'd have a [movie](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) tag on our Movie & TV site used only for movies that just happen to have TV versions. Sound silly, doesn't it?

Users are never going to understand that an [anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime) tag is only for questions that are specific to the anime-version of a series that exists as both anime and manga. Users are going to try and use this for *every* question that is either anime or menga.

But your can't divide a site into large swaths like this. These discussions go back as far back as our Cooking site when some folks were only interested in "savory vs. sweet" while another wanted "vegetarian vs. non-vegetarian."  The tags will convey no useful information. At best it will be a horribly incomplete categorization system.

Comment: I see no problem in having two tags (anime and manga) that are the most extensively used in the site (about half the questions for each, let's assume).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Even at this early stage, usage is completely off the rails, with two questions having *no* descriptive tags beyond "anime". Destroyed and blacklisted.

Comment: @Shog9 Please change the status tag of this thread so other users aren't completely confused when they see it is blacklisted even though the request to blacklist is marked as "declined"

Comment: @atlantiza: read the question carefully: the suggestion was "do allow these tags, so people are able to specify/narrow down about what they are talking."

Comment: @Shog9 Sorry, I was confused since the title seemed to imply that they are requesting to blacklist it; it looks like the mods declined the suggestion of "not allowing" the anime tag. Can we change the title then, to something like "Allow anime tag"?

Comment: @atlantiza: sure.

Comment: @Shog9 Well the manga tag is still allowed so it probably shouldn't be in the title now... Sorry to bother you, and thanks.

Comment: @atlantiza: it's not - I just forgot to remove it from existing questions; thanks for the reminder!

Comment: @Shog9 Please also blacklist movie, light-novel, visual-novel, and live-action. I'm really not going to bother you again!

Comment: You can bother me any time, @atlantiza - but please make a separate meta post for these.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create tags [anime-only](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-only) and [manga-only](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-only)?