# Add "light-novel" to tag blacklist

Tags: feature-request, tags

Since "anime" and "manga" tags are blacklisted, light-novel should be blacklisted as well since it serves the same purpose

Comment: Where is it stated they were blacklisted?

Comment: @Alenanno http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/18/ Note the status tag and Shoq9's response to Robert's answer.

Comment: Ah thanks. :) I didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

<s>I posted a [counter-proposal](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186/should-we-have-an-anime-specific-tag) a little while back which got very little discussion on either side of the argument. In my opinion, we got rid of [anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime) and [manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga) not because they were bad tags, but because they were bad descriptors of what the tags were actually used for and hence were overused. If we used [anime-specific](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-specific) and [manga-specific](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-specific) then there would be no problem. Likewise [light-novel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light-novel) should be changed to be [light-novel-specific](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light-novel-specific) rather than deleted.</s>

I'm not sure I still care strongly about this either way, but I'm posting this as an answer to gauge the opinion of the community and in case anyone else does feel strongly that we should keep this tag.

---

The above now seems obsolete. This tag is only used on [one question](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/162/24), and that question doesn't particularly need it. Rather than blacklisting, which should be avoided except in cases of repeated abuse (because it requires SE involvement), I think it's reasonable just to delete the tag from that question. If anyone feels strongly that this tag should exist, and can come up with a good argument for why, feel free to edit it back into the relevant questions, but please provide an answer here or somewhere else on meta as to why you think so.

Comment: The main part of the problem (I think) was that these tags would be used so much to the point that they would become the most popular tag on a question. The most popular tag is appended to the page's title which influences search engine hits.

Comment: @atlantiza If that's the problem, then I don't think we'll run into the same issue with [tag:light-novel]. It doesn't seem like the kind of tag that will be common, based on the fact that we only have 1 question tagged as such currently.