# What should we do with non-series tags without many uses

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I went through all the tags which only had at most 3 questions tagged. The following are all the ones which do not correspond to a particular series, person, or studio, ordered in the same way they are ordered at https://anime.stackexchange.com/tags. These seem to be the most controversial tags, though there may be other controversies with the larger tags in this category. I've ignored those for now since I think each of them deserves a separate meta post.

[production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/production) [anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics) [music](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) [technology](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) [voice-acting](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-acting) [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) [season](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/season) [prequel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prequel) [origin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origin) [sound-effects](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-effects) [meme](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meme) [mistranslation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mistranslation) [light-novel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light-novel) [live-action](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-action) [manga-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-history) [currently-airing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currently-airing) [doujinshi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doujinshi) [fillers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fillers) [game-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-history) [censorship](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/censorship) [conventions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conventions) [copyright](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright) [crossovers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crossovers) [amv](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amv) [analysis](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) [animation-mistakes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation-mistakes)

It seems to me that some of these are good tags, and some are very clearly not necessary. Which should we keep, which should we merge, and which should we get rid of?

Note: I'm asking this because it seems like applying the changes I propose below to 26 tags on my own without community support would be overstepping my bounds, and also so that we can get a mod to do the merges without bumping questions.

Answer (score 5):

Here are my suggestions. These are based on three principles, namely that A) a tag should be something that someone could legitimately be an expert on, B) tags should not be prone to misuse, and C) we should not have two tags with identical or nearly identical scopes. I've also only commented on tags that I think are not likely to generate a lot of debate; those tags would be better discussed on their own individual posts.

- <s>[production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/production) seems redundant, as we already have [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production) and [manga-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-production). The two open questions on [production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/production) could both be retagged as [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production). The closed one is about Visual Novel production. If the tag were going to be used for questions about production of media other than anime and manga, I'd say keep but rename. As it is now, I say **merge with [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production)** (and remove from the VN question).</s> [status-complete](/questions/tagged/status-complete)
- [anime-physics](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-physics) is a borderline case. I don't see much reason to keep it, but I also don't see much reason to get rid of it. I'll **abstain** on this one.
- [music](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) can probably stay. The only question is whether [music](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) and [theme-song](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-song) are different enough to warrant having two separate tags. However, of the 4 questions tagged with [theme-song](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-song), 3 of them aren't solely about the music from the song, so I say **keep both tags**.
- <s>[technology](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technology) is a strange one. The wiki description says it's to be used both for real-world technology and in-universe technology, which obviously are very different things. I say we **make it only for in-universe technology**. If there are any real-world technology questions which are on topic on this site, we should make a separate tag for them, but if not then we can get rid of it. I'm not really opposed to getting rid of the tag entirely either, but I'll abstain on that point.</s> [status-complete](/questions/tagged/status-complete) Changed tag wiki to reflect that.
- [voice-acting](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voice-acting) seems fine to me. **Keep**.
- [retag](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag) probably should be discussed on it's own meta post, but for now I say **keep**.
- <s>[season](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/season) No need for this. **Burninate**.</s> [status-complete](/questions/tagged/status-complete)
- <s>[prequel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/prequel) I don't see what this is good for. **Destroy**</s> [status-complete](/questions/tagged/status-complete)
- <s>[origin](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/origin) **Merge with [anime-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-history)**</s> [status-complete](/questions/tagged/status-complete)
- [sound-effects](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sound-effects) The single question tagged with this would be better tagged with [japanese-language](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese-language). In principle I think this tag might be okay, though I suspect it would be a subtag of [tropes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tropes).
- [meme](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meme) isn't quite the same as any other tags we have, and it's not prone to misuse. We probably won't get many questions on it, but for now I say **keep**.
- <s>[mistranslation](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mistranslation) **Merge with [japanese-language](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese-language)**</s> [status-complete](/questions/tagged/status-complete) - Note that no synonym was made.
- [fillers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fillers) I have no opinion on this. **Abstain**.
- [light-novel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light-novel) It's questionable whether this is necessary. In my opinion this should be discussed at [Add "light-novel" to tag blacklist](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/275/add-light-novel-to-tag-blacklist) rather than here.
- [live-action](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/live-action) is similar to [light-novel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light-novel). It should be discussed individually on a separate post.
- [manga-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga-history) I propose that we **merge this, [anime-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-history), and [game-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-history) into a broad [history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history) tag**. There isn't too much potential for misuse of such a tag, and there isn't much difference in the scope of these tags.
- [currently-airing](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/currently-airing) **Kill**. Too prone to misuse, and there aren't many other questions that can be asked about this. The one question with this tag should be retagged, but none of the existing tags works. I suggest [anime-resources](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-resources) for these sorts of questions. That, or we could move it to meta as an FAQ question.
- [doujinshi](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doujinshi) Again similar to [light-novel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/light-novel). This should get it's own meta post.
- [fillers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fillers) I'll **abstain**, though I lean towards getting rid of it slightly.
- [game-history](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-history) see above.
- [censorship](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/censorship) is probably okay, though it's almost a subtag of [anime-production](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime-production). **keep**
- [conventions](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/conventions) My trouble with this is, are there any on-topic questions about conventions? **If there are, we can keep it. If not, we should get rid of it**. The only currently tagged question is closed, though it might be a candidate for reopening.
- [copyright](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/copyright) seems fairly broadly off-topic. There are a few questions one can ask about copyright that are on-topic here, but I think it's few enough that we don't need a tag for it. Leaning towards **kill**, though I'm a bit iffy on this one.
- [crossovers](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crossovers) I see no problem with this one, except that a couple of questions that could be tagged with this aren't. **Keep**.
- [amv](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amv) AMVs usually refers to fan productions which are not official. I think they are almost entirely off-topic here. It can very rarely refer to officially produced AMVs by studios, but that is not the norm. As such, I say **kill**.
- <s>[analysis](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/analysis) seems to have been added in the early days, perhaps from [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/) where it is a common tag. However, I think there is no need for it here. **Kill**.</s> [status-complete](/questions/tagged/status-complete)
- [animation-mistakes](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animation-mistakes) I guess I'm okay with. **Keep**.

---

Since this is a very long post and most of the disagreement is likely to be over a small number of tags, I'd suggest voicing any disagreement as a separate answer rather than a comment here so that it can be properly voted on.

Comment: I agree with all. To add onto a few... Kill [analysis] as is an entirely non-constructive tag. Keep [anime-physics] since it is definitely the subject of a lot of "WTF"s in anime. [retag] needs to remain, I think, to keep newbies from tagging it with "whatever". I'd say burn [technology] as I don't think many in-universe tags will be helpful--technology changes between universes. [season] and [prequel]... just WTF... kill. I think I missed one I was going to mention, but I'm running out of characters anyway.

Comment: I agree with the answer, and with @Eric's comment. Pretty good job :)

Comment: Good compilation. I agree with nearly everything you say (and seems like the rest agree as well). I'll get on it soon.