# The tag "visual novel"

Tags: discussion

Ah, the old topic again. First, [anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime) and [manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga) were forbidden, then they were [allowed again](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20/122). I think that over more and more questions, different things came up, whether such tags should be used, or not. Currently, the tags [anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime) and [manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga) aren't used. Should [visual-novel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-novel) be used? Or should questions like [this](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/3862/122) be edited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, the tags [anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anime) and [manga](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/manga) are blacklisted. They were blacklisted because they are meta-tags. So it's not really a case of "they aren't used", but rather a case of "they **can't** be used".

Regarding the [visual-novel](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/visual-novel) tag, I think they should not be allowed either, since they are as much of a meta-tag as the other two.

Either that, or they should all be allowed. But **I think blacklisting is the way to go**.

Comment: How can I see, whether a tag is blacklisted? I don't want to write a fake-question just to try it out. In the worst case, I find a tag that isn't blacklisted.

Comment: You will see it when you try to use the tag. You don't even need to submit a question. If you type "anime" on the tag field, you'll see a message saying that that tag cannot be used.

Comment: No, turns out you'll need to hit the submit button. So I guess there's no other way for you to know whether a tag is blacklisted or not.

Comment: +1 for blacklisting the "medium" meta-tags.

Comment: It's probably easier to delete the tag than it is to blacklist it. Blacklisting requires SE to get involved and is typically only used when a tag is deleted and recreated several times.

Comment: I wonder: If I want to ask a question in general, which tag should I used, when visual-novel is blacklisted?

Comment: @looper I'd suggest we create a [tag:visual-novel-production] tag to take care of questions about production of visual novels. For other sorts of general questions, I think they typically fall into one of the existing tags.

Answer (score 1):

There wasn't any opposition voiced to deleting the tag, so I removed it from the 8 questions which had it. The tag itself will disappear in the near future since there aren't any questions tagged with it anymore.

If the tag continues to be recreated and used in the future, it might be worth blacklisting, but I don't think it's a big enough problem right now to necessitate it.